# Associate multiple radio buttons with a single textbox

Tags: html, django, textbox, radio-button

I am not good with front-end and HTML is what I would ideally like to work with here (if I can avoid engaging js/jquery here). I have a single textbox with multiple radio buttons - say, item1, item2,...item5. Each item1, 2... corresponds to a field. When a user enters, say, 'abc' in a textbox and selects 'item3', it should return all items having 'abc' in item3 field. I can do it with individual textboxes for each item1, 2.. but I need just one textbox associated with all the radio fields.

Here's the relevant html/template code.

```
    <form action={% url 'search-fields-radiofields' %} method="get">

        <div align="left">

            <input type="text" name="name" size="54" />​
            <br><br>

            <input type="radio" id="radio1"name="name">
            <label for="radio1">item1</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio1"name="name">
            <label for="radio2">item2</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio1"name="name">
            <label for="radio3">item3</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio1"name="name">
            <label for="radio4">item4</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio1"name="name">
            <label for="radio5">item5</label>
            <br><br>
            <input id="search_fields" type="submit" value="Search"  size="100"/>        
</div>
</form>
```

Say, the search term is 'test'. And I select item5. Returns a MultiValueDictKeyError with `Get` data of

```
Variable    Value
u'name'[u'test', u'on']
```

. `name` is one of the fields in the db and item5 is supposed to correspond to it. Similarly, if I change the textbox name to 'item1', then `Get` data is

```
Variable    Value
u'item1' [u'test', u'on']
```

I have a dedicated `view` to handle all the radio inputs and it works with individual textboxes corresponding to each of the items. But I need to associate all 5 radio buttons with only 1 textbox as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Solved it from backend myself. The problem was that I was trying to get the request to send just the text value with the key=whatever-radio-is-selected. What I did was looked at the request it was sending which was name=? and textbox=? and then used these two keys to send the right response.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to "associate" the buttons with the text box at all.

What you are missing is that each of the radio buttons themselves needs a `value`. Once you've done that, but given them a *different* name, you're all set.

```
        <input type="text" name="name" size="54" />​

        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="field" value="item1">
        <label for="radio1">item1</label>

        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="field" value="item2">
        <label for="radio2">item2</label>
```

...etc

Now `request.GET` will be `{'name': 'test', 'field': 'item1'}` or whatever.

Comment: This seems to (1)  pick up the value as a default for all requests. In this case, for item1 field, it will always be field:item1. For my problem, I need item1 to be have whatever value is entered in the textbox. Also, (2) if name="field" for all buttons, then I don;t know how the request will distinguish between the different buttons - does label do that? Sorry, longish comment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Solved it as mentioned below.